# Pushing to private gitserver with gitlist

Tags: git, apache, gitlist

I set up a git server on a Debian system and installed gitlist to view the repositories.
All that works really fine, I can see my repositories and clone and push them over HTTP.

My Problem is that the URL to push the repositories isn't the same as the gitlist URL.
Right now I can access gitlist via `http://<IP>/gitlist/` and a repository like this `http://<IP>/gitlist/example.git`

When I want to clone/pull/push them I have to use `http://<IP>/git/example.git` (That's configured in apache)

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/git/repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
```

But I already saw systems running gitlist where you can simply copy the URL from your Browser and use it for git too.

So my Question is, how do I set up apache and gitlist that I can use the URL from the Browser to clone a repository and so on. (`git clone http://<IP>/gitlist/example.git`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your apache configuration.

Rewrite the ScriptAlias that the gitlist is not touched, but git commands can access the data they need (like `info/refs`)

Here is my git.conf (under debian inside /etc/apache/conf.d/):

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/git/repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAliasMatch /gitlist/(.*/(HEAD|info/refs|objects/(info/[^/]+|[0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38}|pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx))|git-(upload|receive)-pack)) /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/$1
```

(Note: you're not using ScriptAlias but ScriptAliasMatch to use regex)